# How to concurrently download multiple S3 objects using GO?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, concurrency, download, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to download 4 objects from S3. Each of them is almost of size 1 MB. If I download them serially, I get a latency of around 40-50ms per object with a total latency of appx 200ms. However, If I try to download them concurrently, the total latency increases to 300ms. I am not sure why concurrent downloads are slower. Can someone help me with what is the correct way to download objects concurrently? Thanks!

Here is the GO code that I am using:

```golang
downloader := s3manager.NewDownloaderWithClient(client)
out := make([][]byte, len(keys))
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

for i := 0; i < len(keys); i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(i int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        wb := &aws.WriteAtBuffer{}
        _, err := downloader.Download(wb, &s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(s3client.bucketName),
            Key:    aws.String(keys[i]),
        })
        out[i] = wb.Bytes()
    }(i)
}
wg.Wait()
return out
```

Comment: What happens if you do the same test with larger objects e.g. 50MB?

Comment: I haven't tried with large objects that are around 50MB in size. But, I did test with 2 objects of 2 MB size each.
If I query them serially I was getting total latency of around 60 ms per object, taking total to 120 ms.
If i query them concurrently, Then the total latency to download both the objects was coming around 460ms

So, Increasing the size of the object and decreasing the number of objects did not help

Comment: I'm not too surprised that sequential fetches of a small number of small objects is overall faster than concurrent fetches of those same objects. I'd hope that this would flip, however, at some larger number of larger objects. If it's simple to do, I'd be interested in the results of 10 consecutive 50MB downloads vs. 10 concurrent 50MB downloads. Is that simple for you to test?

Comment: Sadly, its not easy for me to test right now as I will have to raise permissions with my employer, which will take a day or so. Will get back to you once I test this.